# Киево-Печерская Лавра — прописные буквы

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Понятно, что "Киево-Печерская" (кстати, именно Печ**е**рская, а не Печорская, как многие упорно говорят) — это название. Но лавра — это любой мужской монастырь. По логике это слово должно писаться с маленькой буквы. Или тут оно уже стало как бы нарицательным, преобразовавшись в название?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Лавра - название некоторых больших православных мужских монастырей. Слово "лавра" - нарицательное существительное. Пишется с маленькой буквы.  В словарях, которые открываются на Яндексе, везде  в названиях разных монастырей - маленькая буква. Возможно, написание большой буквы пошло от закрепленного в официальных документах неправильного написания?

Дополняю цитатой из справочника Розенталя:

Написание названий, связанных с религией, подчиняется общим правилам употребления прописных букв.

...
9.      В названиях церквей, монастырей, учебных заведений, икон слова церковь, храм, монастырь, академия, семинария, икона (образ) пишутся со строчной буквы, а их названия и все собственные имена в названиях – с прописной, например: храм Зачатия Праведной Анны, Казанский собор, **Киево-Печерская лавра**, икона Донской Божией Матери, образ Знамения Божией Матери; собор Сан-Стефана.

Comment: @Ларf, это какой из Розенталей?

А, нашел...
http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/238/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9

Но это чуть ли не советских времен рекомедация... В этом вопросе много могло воды утечь...

Answer (score 2):

Согласна, что нет никаких причин писать с прописной слово "лавра". Добавлю, что и в академических словарях по украинскому языку закреплено написание со строчной: "Києво-Печерська лавра". "Грамота" также дает строчную: 
*ЛАВРА, -ы; ж. [греч. laura - многолюдное место]
Название крупных православных мужских монастырей, непосредственно подчинённых Синоду. **Киево-Печерская л. Александро-Невская л.***

Answer (score 1):

```
http://na-journal.ru/publikacija-stati-v-zhurnale
```

Есть различие в употреблении прописной и строчной буквы в светской и церковной документации.  Допускается множество ошибок при составлении светской документации, что идёт в разрыв с церковным написанием. Осознав проблему, НАЦЖУРНАЛ собрал материал, который позволил бы создать рекомендации при написании таких текстов.Можно руководствоваться им:

Если храм освящен во имя святого, то в его названии все слова, кроме имен собственных, пишутся со строчной буквы. Например, храм во имя святителя Тримифунтского Спиридона. Если храм освящен в честь какого-либо праздника или иконы, то название праздника и иконы сохраняет прописную букву.  Например, храм в честь Успения Пресвятой Богородицы. Если название храма дается в сокращенной форме, то оно также пишется с прописной буквы. Например, Успенский храм.  Некоторые храмы имеют собственные названия, единичные. Эти названия пишутся с прописной буквы. Например, Кулич и Пасха. Если указано местоположение монастыря, то оно пишется с прописной буквы, так как название города, в котором расположена обитель, вошло в название. Например, Московский Данилов монастырь.

Слово "Лавра" всегда пишется с прописной буквы: Троице-Сергиева Лавра, Киево-Печерская Лавра, Почаевская Успенская Лавра.

Но пока это не узаконено, на разных сайтах Вы найдёте разное написание.

Comment: По ссылке что-то ничего понятного не открывается. Правильное написание слов мы ищем не на "разных сайтах", а в академических словарях. Нет? Дополнила ответ цитатой из Розенталя.

Comment: Да, почему-то сохранилась не вся ссылка, сейчас попробую повторитьhttp://na-journal.ru/stati/9-nauchnyj-aspekt-2-2012-gumanitarnye-nauki/76-razlichija-v-upotreblenii-propisnoj-i-strochnoj-bukvy-v-svetskoj-dokumentacii-i-v-cerkovnoj-tradicii.
Это статья в ж."Научный аспект " - материал научной конференциии - употребл. прописной или строчной буквы в словах, связанных с религией, при составлении документов. Даны рекомендации для написания таких текстов.

Comment: Я привела её в доказательство мысли о том, что этот вопрос в стадии разработки.Учёные считают, что нужно прийти к общему мнению при написании текстов документов, чтобы написания в светской литературе не расходились с написаниями слов в религиозной. Религия стала занимать много места в нашей жизни, в документах нужно  учитывать традиции, сложившиеся в церковно-религиозных и религиозно-философских текстах.Поэтому и разночтения. Где-то пишут по светским правилам (словари слово лавра пишут с маленькой), а где-то по церковным  - с большой. Автор вопроса увидел второе.

Answer (score 1):

.........................................................."И ты тоже прав!"
..........................................................(из анекдота)

Написание "по Розенталю" входит в противоречие с рекомендуемым Патриархией. Это не единичный случай. Патриархия выступает за восстановоение порядка, когда заглавная буква в названии или должности была бы показателем не столько собственности имени, сколько особого отношения к объекту или его "святости".

В другой бы ситуации от рекомендаций Патриархии можно было бы и отмахнуться (всяк сверчок - знай свой шесток) или ограничить подобное употребление заглавных внутренними церковными нуждами, но у нас сложнее... В отдельных случаях официальная орфография идет навстречу церковной (в отношении некоторых праздников, должностей и проч.) Поэтому совсем отмахиваться нельзя.

А в данном случае ещё и ситуация неоднозначная. Слово "Лавра", как и отмечается в самом вопросе, в сочетании с "Киево-Печерской" (и, возможно, ещё Александро-Невской) воспринимается как часть названия, особенно когда речь идет не о самой лавре, давно потерявшей исходный статус, а об архитектурно-музейном комплексе.

Тем не менее, рекомендаций о написания с заглавной вне церковной сферы я бы пока избегал.

Comment: Лопатин (21 век, в отличие от Розенталя) повторяет  то же самое, с теми же примерами. П.186.)